# CheckAll/UncheckAll issue with Subscribe ? Knockout

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js

I been trying to do checkbox Checkall and UnCheckall using subscribe and i'm partially successful doing that but i am unable to find a fix in couple of scenarios when i am dealing with `subscribe` .

**Using subscribe :**

I am here able to checkAll uncheckAll but when i uncheck a child checkbox i.e `test1` or `test2` i need my parent checkbox `name` also to be unchecked and in next turn if i check `test1` the parent checkbox should be checked i.e keeping condition both child checkboxes are checked .

For fiddle : [**Click Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3fgzp10/)

**ViewModel :**

```
self.selectedAllBox.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (newValue == true) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.People(), function (item) {
                item.sel(true);
            });
        } else {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.People(), function (item) {
                item.sel(false);

            });
        }
    });
```

The same scenario can be done perfectly in easy way using `computed` but due some performance issues i need to use `subscribe` which is best way it wont fire like computed onload .

**Reference :** Using computed same thing is done perfectly check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AneL9/)

I tried to use `change` event in individual checkbox binding but its a dead end till now.

Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a similar problem in my own application a couple of years ago using manual subscriptions. Although the computed observable method is concise and easy to understand, it suffers from poor performance when there's a large number of items. Hopefully the code below speaks for itself:

```
function unsetCount(array, propName) {
    // When an item is added to the array, set up a manual subscription
    function addItem(item) {
        var previousValue = !!item[propName]();
        item[propName]._unsetSubscription = item[propName].subscribe(function (latestValue) {
            latestValue = !!latestValue;
            if (latestValue !== previousValue) {
                previousValue = latestValue; 
                unsetCount(unsetCount() + (latestValue ? -1 : 1));
            }
        });
        return previousValue;
    }
    // When an item is removed from the array, dispose the subscription
    function removeItem(item) {
        item[propName]._unsetSubscription.dispose();
        return !!item[propName]();
    }

    // Initialize
    var tempUnsetCount = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(array(), function (item) {
        if (!addItem(item)) {
            tempUnsetCount++;
        }
    });
    var unsetCount = ko.observable(tempUnsetCount);

    // Subscribe to array changes
    array.subscribe(function (changes) {
        var tempUnsetCount = unsetCount();
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(changes, function (change) {
            if (change.moved === undefined) {
                if (change.status === 'added') {
                    if (!addItem(change.value))
                        tempUnsetCount++;
                } else {
                    if (!removeItem(change.value))
                        tempUnsetCount--;
                }
            }
        });
        unsetCount(tempUnsetCount);
    }, null, 'arrayChange');

    return unsetCount;
}
```

You'll still use a computed observable in your viewmodel for the the select-all value, but now it'll only need to check the *unselected count*:

```
self.unselectedPeopleCount = unsetCount(self.People, 'Selected');

self.SelectAll = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function() {
        return self.People().length &&  self.unselectedPeopleCount() === 0;
    },
    write: function(value) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.People(), function (person) {
            person.Selected(value);
        });
    }
}).extend({rateLimit:0});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/dwnv81j0/

Answer (score 2):

Your subscription only applies to edits on the selectedAllBox.  To do what you want, you'll need subscriptions on every Person checkbox as well, to check for the right conditions and uncheck the selectedAllBox in the right situations there.

It strikes me as odd that this would be acceptable but using computed() is not.  Maybe you should reconsider that part of your answer.  I would much rather compute a "isAllSelected" value based on my viewModel state, then bind the selectedAllBox to that.

Comment: @patrick that a great insight . yes i have tried subscription for child checkboxes i.e `event:{change:$root.checkevaluate}` . In `checkevaluate` i am trying to do my evaluations in a proper way but i am stuck .

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis yes i do believe its the best but at an expense of performance i.e if i have `n` checkboxes the computed will run `n` times onload isn't it .

Comment: `patrick` can you share a code snippet you referring to i.e`isAllselected` . cheers

Comment: Honestly, I do not see any problem with your answer at http://jsfiddle.net/AneL9/ .  No solution with a intermediate property would be better.

Comment: @supercool perhaps, but the first rule of optimization: Don't. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski agreed man i tried to convince my TA but my hands are tied and i need to do their way . @matthew i honestly believe the same but see people are trying to kill code on the name of `optimization`

Answer (score 1):

The computed approach is the right way to do this. You can improve some performance issues by using `pureComputed` and by using `rateLimit`. Both require more recent versions of Knockout than the 2.2.1 used in your example (3.2 and 3.1, respectively).

```
self.SelectAll = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function() {
        var item = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.People(), function(item) {
            return !item.Selected();
        });
        return item == null;           
    },
    write: function(value) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.People(), function (person) {
            person.Selected(value);
        });
    }
}).extend({rateLimit:1});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/AneL9/98/

Comment: ok michael i just read the docs on ratelimit . it will delay updating observable value to lastest typed one right . so is there any chance this ratelimit will help computed not to fire onLoad and should work after load .

Comment: i hope you can see bigger picture here mate i may have 1000 checkboxes or more with data coming in .By default i bind each checkbox to `false` and i feel there is no need of computed onLoad to evaluate again what to bind to 1000 checkboxes because its false i mentioned but computed is really helpful after load tough .